# Several Questions Regarding Color Space Representation

Tags: image-processing, matlab, color

As part of my seminar, I have to make a full representation on the many color spaces. I took a deep dive in the internet and on YouTube and managed to gather a lot of information. BUT I have a few questions, regarding the XYZ color space (also known as CIE XYZ 1931 color space).

(1) Why do images in XYZ color space look darker than RGB? In other words, why is X a more saturated red, Y a more saturated green and Z a more saturated blue?

[image]

(2) Why does the sum of each row of the RGB -> XYZ matrix transform have to be 1?

(3)Regarding the HSV color space, what is the intuition behind this conversion?
[image]

(4) And the last question, why did we partition the image to color and brightness and perform a spatial filter on it to transform the image to S-CIELAB?

[image]

Thanks in advance, any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Generally, these are four questions that have little to do with each other and should really not have been asked in the same question. 
(1) If the same image (assuming it's representable in both spaces) looks different when converted to the other space, your conversion isn't doing what it should: representing the same image with respect to a different color model. so, there's no answer to that other than "any step in the process between the XYZ data and your eye is not doing the equivalent thing to what happens to RGB data, and it shows"

Comment: (2) It doesn't have to be like that, if that's the case for *your* definition of some color space, that's a design choice.

Comment: (3) which intuition? why must there be an intuition?

Comment: (4) is pretty broad and expects us to explain color pattern perception. It's not "just" a color space. I think you'd really want to ask this very much separately and explain in much more detail what you've researched so far (generally, "youtube research" sounds like... not that much)

Comment: @MarcusMüller well, could you please send me a link to an article/lecture about S-CIELAB color representation? I've already read two articles and still don't know what's the purpose of spatial filters and how does this representation used to evaluate image quality?